# How to speed up old iPad 2 (maybe replace iOS?)

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

My old iPad 2 is unusably slow, even just to browse the internet (such as by using Google Chrome). It's nearly a piece of trash at this point.

I've tried a complete factory reset multiple times.

**If I'm willing to do pretty much anything to this iPad at this point (jailbreak, roll back to previous iOS, or install a different operating system entirely, etc), what can I do so that I can browse websites easily and quickly?**

I'd love to use the latest version of Google Chrome or Firefox if possible, but at this point I don't even really care, and I don't care what OS I use either.

P.S. The back of my iPad says A1395 16 GB, which means it's the "iPad 2 (Wi-Fi)" from 2011 according to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471). It's running iOS 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical thing that might help is if your battery is failing - putting in a new one might pep up the processor.

The actual browser is going to be hard to make faster and jailbreaking and running another OS is going to be likely far less optimized than iOS 9 is already for that architecture.

Your main help for browsing websites quickly would be to select websites that don't use javascript much or block that from running and consume text / html / light css.

Comment: You sound like you know what you're talking about, so I appreciate your answer.  So if iOS 9 is optimized for the hardware, why wouldn't apps (such as Google Chrome or whatever other browser) perform as quickly as back in 2011 or 2012?

I'd basically like to roll back to exactly what I had when I bought the iPad. It would be acceptable to use a 2011 browser. Javascript worked fine back then.

Comment: The size of web pages alone is rising as fast or faster than the hardware can grow in my opinion. And the JavaScript / programming is being added at a rate faster. Generally - more stuff on the “same” page. That assumes your CPU isn’t throttled due to a bad battery.